# Django Tastpie Send using Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, tastypie

My view .

```
class EventRVSPResource(ModelResource):
event      = fields.ForeignKey(EventResource, 'event')
created_by = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'created_by')  
class Meta:
    queryset = EventRsvp.objects.all()
    authorization = Authorization()
    resource_name = 'eventrvsp'
    filtering = {
        'event':ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        'created_by': ALL,

    }
```

but sending data  using curl it is working fine. it showing 201

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"created_by": "/mobapp/api/v1/user/1/","event": "/mobapp/api/v1/eventlist/5/","notes": "Going","past_status": "DG","status": "Y"}' http://192.168.1.8:9000/mobapp/api/v1/eventrvsp/
```

My Http request to django-tastypie.But still it is showing error.I dont whats wrong with it

```
var url = "http://192.168.1.8:9000/mobapp/api/v1/eventrvsp/";
 var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
     // function called when the response data is available
     onload : function(e) {
         Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
         alert('success');
     },
     // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
     onerror : function(e) {
         Ti.API.debug();
         alert(e.error);
     },
     timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
 });
 // Prepare the connection.
 client.open("POST", url);
 // Send the request.
 client.send({"created_by": "/mobapp/api/v1/user/1/","event": "/mobapp/api/v1/eventlist/4/","notes": "Going","past_status": "DG","status": "Y"});
```

Comment: and what is the error???

Comment: IT DONT SHOW ERROR...IT JUST GOES TO ONERROR ALERT ERROR.... BUT USING CURL IT IS POSTING RIGHT..USING HTTP REQUEST IT WAS NOT POSTING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you need to set header "content-type" to "application/json" and use JSON.stringify

you can find ref here:http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interacting.html#creating-a-new-resource-post

**Note: always place `setRequestHeader` after `open` befor `send`**

```
 var data = JSON.stringify({created_by:"/mobapp/api/v1/user/1/",event:"/mobapp/api/v1/eventlist/5/",notes:"Going",past_status:"DG",status:"Y"});
.
.
.
.
.




    client.open("POST", url);
client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");  
client.send(data);
```